# How to align the radio button text to the vertically center in QML

Tags: qml

I am new to Qt-QML.
I am trying to implement the radio buttons based on the size of the parent window and text to be aligned vertically center
But, the text beside radio buttons is not aligning vertically center.
Could you please help me where I am doing wrong?

```
Window {
id: mainwindow
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

function getActualValue( percent ,  value)
{
    var percentageValue = Math.round((percent*value)/100);
    return percentageValue;
}

GroupBox {
    id: groupboxId
    title: qsTr("Log Meas")
    font.pixelSize: mainwindow.getActualValue(2, mainwindow.width)
    width: mainwindow.width/4
    height: mainwindow.height/8
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    RowLayout {
        RadioButton {
            id: radioButton1
            checked: true
            font.pixelSize: mainwindow.getActualValue(2, mainwindow.width)
            text: qsTr("Imperial")

            indicator: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: mainwindow.getActualValue(3, mainwindow.height)
                implicitHeight: mainwindow.getActualValue(3, mainwindow.height)
                radius: 9
                border.color: radioButton1.activeFocus ? "red" : "gray"
                border.width: 1
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    visible: radioButton1.checked
                    color: "#555"
                    radius: 9
                    anchors.margins: 4
                }
            }

            contentItem: Text {
                text: radioButton1.text
                font: radioButton1.font
                opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                color: radioButton1.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                leftPadding: radioButton1.indicator.width + radioButton1.spacing
                }
        }

        RadioButton {
            id: radioButton2
            checked: false
            font.pixelSize: mainwindow.getActualValue(2, mainwindow.width)
            text: qsTr("Metric")

            indicator: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: mainwindow.getActualValue(3, mainwindow.height)
                implicitHeight: mainwindow.getActualValue(3, mainwindow.height)
                radius: 9
                border.color: radioButton2.activeFocus ? "darkblue" : "gray"
                border.width: 1

                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    visible: radioButton2.checked
                    color: "#555"
                    radius: 9
                    anchors.margins: 4
                }
            }

            contentItem: Text {
                text: radioButton2.text
                font: radioButton2.font
                opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                color: radioButton2.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                leftPadding: radioButton2.indicator.width + radioButton2.spacing

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The output looks like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h14SN.png)

Comment: Please try [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-radiobutton), you may see where u re mistaken:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code is below. The biggest issue is that the text was indeed vertically centered. It's the indicator that was not.

Note, customizing controls is normally best done in fixed units of pixels and most of them assume that. If you really want dynamic scalability of controls you need to make sure everything (including all of the implicit sizes, paddings, spacings, etc.) are scaling appropriately.

Reviewing the base implementation here can help you with that:

https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/quickcontrols2/basic/RadioButton.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
id: mainwindow
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

function getActualValue( percent ,  value)
{
    var percentageValue = Math.round((percent*value)/100);
    return percentageValue;
}

GroupBox {
    id: groupboxId
    title: qsTr("Log Meas")
    font.pixelSize: mainwindow.getActualValue(2, mainwindow.width)
    width: mainwindow.width/4
    height: mainwindow.height/8
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    RowLayout {
        RadioButton {
            id: radioButton1
            checked: true
            font.pixelSize: mainwindow.getActualValue(2, mainwindow.width)
            text: qsTr("Imperial")
            implicitWidth: contentItem.contentWidth + indicator.width + 2 * spacing
            implicitHeight: indicator.implicitHeight

            indicator: Rectangle {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                implicitWidth: mainwindow.getActualValue(3, mainwindow.height)
                implicitHeight: mainwindow.getActualValue(3, mainwindow.height)
                radius: 9
                border.color: radioButton1.activeFocus ? "red" : "gray"
                border.width: 1
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    visible: radioButton1.checked
                    color: "#555"
                    radius: 9
                    anchors.margins: 4
                }
            }

            contentItem: Text {
                text: radioButton1.text
                font: radioButton1.font
                opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                color: radioButton1.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                leftPadding: radioButton1.indicator.width + radioButton1.spacing
                }
        }

        RadioButton {
            id: radioButton2
            checked: false
            font.pixelSize: mainwindow.getActualValue(2, mainwindow.width)
            text: qsTr("Metric")
            implicitWidth: contentItem.contentWidth + indicator.width + 2 * spacing
            implicitHeight: indicator.implicitHeight

            indicator: Rectangle {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                implicitWidth: mainwindow.getActualValue(3, mainwindow.height)
                implicitHeight: mainwindow.getActualValue(3, mainwindow.height)
                radius: 9
                border.color: radioButton2.activeFocus ? "darkblue" : "gray"
                border.width: 1

                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    visible: radioButton2.checked
                    color: "#555"
                    radius: 9
                    anchors.margins: 4
                }
            }

            contentItem: Text {
                text: radioButton2.text
                font: radioButton2.font
                opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
                color: radioButton2.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                leftPadding: radioButton2.indicator.width + radioButton2.spacing
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you David for explaining and fixing the bug